# Lambert conformal conic projection - Europe

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, lambert-conformal-conic

I am trying to calculate map of Europe in Lambert projection. I am using formula from Wikipedia ([Lambert wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection)), but calculation is very slow in comparison with Mercator. I know, there are `sin`, `cos`, `cotg` and `pow` to calculate (Mercator has only one `tan` and `ln`), but the difference is almost 30 minutes (Mercator is done in about 3 minutes).

Is there some kind of speed up, or similar projection, that can be used ? I also need to put result into image with width and hight. For Mercator, I am using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983099/converting-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-coordinate. Can it be altered to Lambert (or Lambert similar) projection ? Because if I use same approach only witch changed formulas for projection, Lambert is moved to upper part of image and I can see only part of Europe)

**EDIT: Added code**

```
double longitude = lon * (MPI / 180.0);
double latitude = lat * (MPI / 180.0);

double lambertPhi = this->lambertF * pow(cot(0.25 * MPI + 0.5 * latitude), this->lambertN);

lonOut = lambertPhi * sinf(this->lambertN * longitude);
latOut = this->lambertPhi0 - lambertPhi * cosf(this->lambertN * longitude);
```

All **this->** variables are precomputed only once

Comment: (1) What software are you using?  (2) Are you concerned about the *moon* "Europa" or the earth *continent* "Europe"?

Comment: n, rho0 and F are all constants for a particular projected CRS. Are you calculating them outside the main loop and reusing the results?

Comment: @whuber I am not using any SW, I am writing code myself in C++. I am concerner about the continent "Europe".

Comment: @mkennedy Yes.. all of those are calculated in Init function. Then those values are reused

Comment: Whether or not your code can be made faster depends on how it currently performs the computation.  Could you post the essential part of your code?

Comment: Thanks.  How many points are you projecting?  During three minutes with one core you should be able to project at least 10^9 points with the Mercator projection, but no map really needs that many points.  (If you are transforming an image you shouldn't be computing the projection of every pixel and if you are transforming vector data you would be processing invisible details.)  Perhaps the issue to address concerns how to simplify the map features rather than how to speed up the calculation of the Lambert conformal conic projection.

Comment: I am doing that only once, so speed is not problem for Mercator (if I change something, I got new map in three minutes). But for lambert, it tooks up to 1 hour and even than result is incorrect (translated) and not covers same area as for Mercator (with same "bounding box" coordinates)

Comment: You should be able to produce a new map within a fraction of a second: three minutes is ridiculously slow. Thus I am suggesting your problem is not particular to the LCC projection but is due to a huge underlying inefficiency.